# SoftLayer blockstorage credential

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I want to get credential data for storage by api.
so i tried to below URL

```
SoftLayer_Network_Storage/8884475.json?objectMask=mask[serviceResourceBackendIpAddress,bytesUsed,osTypeId,allowedIpAddresses,parentVolume.volumeStatus,credentials,serviceResource.datacenter]
```

but i can't get a credential.

so i tried another api.

```
SoftLayer_Network_Storage/8884475/Credentials.json?objectMask=mask[credentials]
```

but can't.

How do I get to know the credential?

thanks.

Comment: your question looks duplicated take a look at this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35408971/how-get-the-softlayer-storage-credendials

Answer (score 0):

After applying this [SoftLayer_Network_Storage::getCredentials](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/getCredentials), the response displays empty values using your`network  Storage Id`.
But I think that you want credentials related to `Authorized hosts`. If I’m right, below is an example that shows you: `“Username”`, `“Password”`, `“Host IQN”` for authorized hosts (Bare Metal Server, Virtual Server, IP Address).

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/8884475/getObject?objectMask=mask[id,username,allowedVirtualGuests[fullyQualifiedDomainName,allowedHost[name,credential[username,password]]],allowedHardware[fullyQualifiedDomainName,allowedHost[name,credential[username,password]]],allowedIpAddresses[ipAddress,allowedHost[name,credential[username,password]]]]

Method: GET
```